# fedup says "Continue with the upgrade at your own risk" - what's next?

Tags: fedora, rpm

While trying to upgrade Fedora 20 to Fedora 21, I got a message:

```
WARNING: problems were encountered during transaction test:
  broken dependencies
    async-http-client-1.7.22-1.fc20.noarch requires netty-3.6.6-2.fc20.noarch
    xorg-x11-drv-r128-6.9.2-1.fc20.x86_64 requires xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.14.4-11.fc20.x86_64
Continue with the upgrade at your own risk.
```

What should I do next? There is no --force of --nodeps switch for fedup.

Update: there are no dependency problems reported by `package-cleanup --problems` on the original system. The problem is that xorg-x11-drv-r128 doesn't have a new version in Fedora 21, but its dependency xorg-x11-server-Xorg is going to be upgraded to an incompatible version. Yet xorg-x11-drv-r128 cannot be uninstalled without `--nodeps`, as it's needed by xorg-x11-drivers.

Comment: You should upgrade the dependencies before you proceed.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out fedup doesn't actually fail (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1098886). Rebooting the system would upgrade it. The packages listed in the beginning of every line are obsolete in Fedora, since there is no replacement for them with satisfactory dependencies. If you need any of those packages, write them down so you can look for replacements later. Once you get a working system, run `yum check` and `yum distro-sync` to identify and resolve dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

The "risk" referred to in the message is a generic message.  There is no need to remove those packages. I also got a list of packages with broken dependencies when I was about to upgrade my F20, and I didn't remove them. Just recognize that they may work or may not in the new F21. Of course, you will have to figure out how to update them after the system upgrade.

Comment: Welcome.  Answers on SU are intended to be definitive.  Your answer doesn't really provide much more information than the fedup message.  It would probably be more appropriate as a comment (which shouldn't take you long to earn enough rep for).

Comment: My short answer should be "Go ahead, no need to remove those packages", because I don't agree with the first answer. I think it is a valid answer, but I can remove it if it's your wish :)

Comment: I made the answer more definitive based on your comment.  However, can you expand the answer to talk about the nature of the risk (could someone end up turning a working OS into a non-functional OS), what precautions to take before the upgrade, how to recover if major things don't work, and generally what the post-upgrade procedure would be to update the dependencies?  You're encouraging the OP to ignore the warnings so it would be appropriate to put it in  perspective and provide some guidance on the potential consequences and how to deal with them.

Comment: You are correct. Fedup actually finishes successfully despite the warnings. Rebooting Fedora would upgrade it. It sounds like future versions of fedup would make it more clear: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1098886